# VolumePreference ask for permission

Tags: android, xamarin, android-permissions

What's the proper way to ask for permission to use "READ_PHONE_STATE" when using VolumePreference streamType="music" in my PreferenceScreen? Galaxy S7 needs this permission idk why, works with no problem on my other devices including lg g6 running android 7.0 same as g7.

Comment: Upvote, because idk too ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯